# Parse string of file path to json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the list of URL like below. How to convert it into complete json object?

My array of URLs.

```
[
"path1/subpath1/file1.doc","path1/subpath1/file2.doc","path1/subpath2/file1.doc","path1/subpath2/file2.doc","path2/subpath1/file1.doc","path2/subpath1/file2.doc","path2/subpath2/file1.doc","path2/subpath2/file2.doc","path2/subpath2/additionalpath1/file1.doc"
]
```

I want this as json object like:

```
{
   "path1":{
      "subpath1":["file1.doc","file2.doc"],
      "subpath2":["file1.doc","file2.doc"]
   },
   "path2":{
      "subpath1":["file1.doc","file2.doc"],
      "subpath2":["file1.doc","file2.doc"],
      "additionalpath1":{
          "additionalpath1":["file1.doc"]
      }
   }
}
```

How to do this?

I tried it with the below code snippets. But there are few folder objects are missing.

If you try this code you will find that `test1` and additional `objects` are missing:

```
<html>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<body>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
let paths = [ "admin/640954.jpg", "admin/test1/3m-nd.jpg", 
"admin/test1/Acct.png", "admin/test1/additional/111.gif", "admin/test1/additional/Aard.jpg", 
"dp/151292.jpg", "dp/151269.jpg", "dp/1515991.jpg" ];


function getMap(urls){
    var map = {};
    urls.forEach(function(url){
        var parts = url.split("/");
        makePath(map, parts);
    })
    return map;
}

function makePath(map,parts){
    var currentPath = map;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < parts.length - 1 ; i++ ){
            if(i == parts.length -2 ){
                currentPath[parts[i]]  = currentPath[parts[i]] || [];
                currentPath[parts[i]].push(parts[++i]);
            }else{
                currentPath[parts[i]] =  currentPath[parts[i]] || {};
                currentPath = currentPath[parts[i]];
            }
    }

}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(getMap(paths));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can do this with a recursive mapping algorithm.

Comment: In which language are you coding?

Comment: @MohitMutha Look at the tags.

Comment: You could grab everything after the last forward slash. What have you already tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an array of paths into JSON structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248245/how-to-convert-an-array-of-paths-into-json-structure)

Comment: Hi the given link gives completely the object at the end. But I want string of array of filenames if no folder name in the string. i.e. The output is not coming as per the given output. Could you please re-write how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.split("/")` and iterate over the results, creating properties in nested objects:

```js
let paths = [
  "path1/subpath1/file111.doc",
  "path1/subpath1/file112.doc",
  "path1/subpath2/file121.doc",
  "path1/subpath2/file122.doc",
  "path2/subpath1/file211.doc",
  "path2/subpath1/file212.doc",
  "path2/subpath2/file221.doc",
  "path2/subpath2/file222.doc",
  "path2/additionalpath3/additionalpath1/file2311.doc"
];

let treePath = {};
paths.forEach(path => {
  let levels = path.split("/");
  let file = levels.pop();

  let prevLevel = treePath;
  let prevProp = levels.shift();

  levels.forEach(prop => {
    prevLevel[prevProp] = prevLevel[prevProp] || {};
    prevLevel = prevLevel[prevProp];
    prevProp = prop;
  });

  prevLevel[prevProp] = (prevLevel[prevProp] || []).concat([file]);
});

console.log(treePath);
```

Or:

```js
let paths = [
  "path1/subpath1/file111.doc",
  "path1/subpath1/file112.doc",
  "path1/subpath2/file121.doc",
  "path1/subpath2/file122.doc",
  "path2/subpath1/file211.doc",
  "path2/subpath1/file212.doc",
  "path2/subpath2/file221.doc",
  "path2/subpath2/file222.doc",
  "path2/additionalpath3/additionalpath1/file2311.doc"
];

let treePath = {};
paths.forEach(path => {
  let levels = path.split("/");
  let file = levels.pop();

  levels.reduce((prev, lvl, i) => {
    return prev[lvl] = (levels.length - i - 1) ? prev[lvl] || {} : (prev[lvl] || []).concat([file]);
  }, treePath);
});

console.log(treePath);
```

Comment: If I use below string, then `test1` object is missing. `let paths = [
"admin/640954_15681069_2837056_82dea68d_image.jpg",
"admin/test1/3m-adjustable-notebook-riser-laptop-stand-740x740.jpg",
"admin/test1/Acct-Mgmt-Templates-1024x611.png",
"admin/test1/additional/111.gif",
"admin/test1/additional/Adminto-Admin-Dashboard.jpg",
"dp/1512966420652.jpg",
"dp/1512966492869.jpg",
"dp/1515556524991.jpg"
];`

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Dude. The expected result is, the file names should be array of string. and folder names should be object name. I'm receiving the list of string from server side. I have to change the string to folder view like tree view. all the folder names should be the parent li and the .doc, .jpg files will be the least child.

Comment: Dude. Your specification is ambiguous. Dude. That's why I asked what's the result. Dude. That's why nobody could meet them, because they make no sense. Dude. The `test1` folder has both subfolders and files. Dude. When a folder has subfolders, it is an object. Dude. When a folder has files, it is an array. Dude. If it has files and subfolders **at the same time** what could it be? Dude. Something can't be an object and an array at the same time. Dude.

Comment: :). How to achieve it then? I wanna show a list of folder only in a tree view. when they click on the corresponding folder, I will show the object inside.

Comment: Look, I'm sorry if I was rude. You don't have to accept my (or any other) answer if it didn't solve/help with your issue. About the question, it is still really hard to figure out what you need. For example, in this last comment, you mention *when they click*, click where? Your question is about converting an object into another, there's apparently no clicking involved. If you are using a plugin of some sort, you have to show it...

Answer (score 1):

I have made Half code for you. check if it is helpful for you.

You can use it and can made some changes to achieve your goal.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = '"path1/subpath1/file1.doc","path1/subpath1/file2.doc","path1/subpath2/file1.doc","path1/subpath2/file2.doc","path2/subpath1/file1.doc","path2/subpath1/file2.doc","path2/subpath2/file1.doc","path2/subpath2/file2.doc","path2/subpath2/additionalpath1/file1.doc"';
    var res = str.split(",");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[0];

    var finalresult = [];
    var innerarray = [];
    var outer = [];
    var outer1 = [];
    var inner =[];
    jQuery.each( res, function( i, val ) {
      res1 = val.split("/");
      jQuery.each( res1, function( i2, val1 ) 
      {
            if(i2 == 0 && !(outer.includes(val1)))
            {
                outer.push(val1);
            }
            else if(i2 == 1 && !(outer1.includes(val1)))
            {
                outer1.push(val1);
            }
            else if(!(inner.includes(val1)))
            {
                inner.push(val1);
            }
        console.log(outer);
      });

    });

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function filePathOject (arr) {
  const ret = {};
  arr.forEach((path) => {
    const dirs = path.split('/');
    const filename = dirs.pop();

    let dirObject = ret;
    dirs.forEach((dir, i) => {
      if (i === dirs.length - 1) {
        dirObject[dir] = dirObject[dir] || [];
        dirObject[dir].push(filename);
      } else {
        dirObject[dir] = dirObject[dir] || {};
      }
      dirObject = dirObject[dir];
    });
  });

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: If I use below string, then `test1` object is missing. `let paths = [
"admin/640954_15681069_2837056_82dea68d_image.jpg",
"admin/test1/3m-adjustable-notebook-riser-laptop-stand-740x740.jpg",
"admin/test1/Acct-Mgmt-Templates-1024x611.png",
"admin/test1/additional/111.gif",
"admin/test1/additional/Adminto-Admin-Dashboard.jpg",
"dp/1512966420652.jpg",
"dp/1512966492869.jpg",
"dp/1515556524991.jpg"
];`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
var urls = [
"path1/subpath1/file1.doc","path1/subpath1/file2.doc","path1/subpath2/file1.doc","path1/subpath2/file2.doc","path2/subpath1/file1.doc","path2/subpath1/file2.doc","path2/subpath2/file1.doc","path2/subpath2/file2.doc","path2/subpath2/additionalpath1/file1.doc"
]

function getMap(urls){
var map = {};

urls.forEach(function(url){
    var parts = url.split("/");
    makePath(map, parts);
})
return map;
}

function makePath(map,parts){
    var currentPath = map;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < parts.length - 1 ; i++ ){
            if(i == parts.length -2 ){
                currentPath[parts[i]]  = currentPath[parts[i]] || [];
                currentPath[parts[i]].push(parts[++i]);
            }else{
                currentPath[parts[i]] =  currentPath[parts[i]] || {};
                currentPath = currentPath[parts[i]];
            }
    }

}
getMap()
```

Left one part for you :)

Comment: If I use below string, then `test1` object is missing. `let paths = [
"admin/640954_15681069_2837056_82dea68d_image.jpg",
"admin/test1/3m-adjustable-notebook-riser-laptop-stand-740x740.jpg",
"admin/test1/Acct-Mgmt-Templates-1024x611.png",
"admin/test1/additional/111.gif",
"admin/test1/additional/Adminto-Admin-Dashboard.jpg",
"dp/1512966420652.jpg",
"dp/1512966492869.jpg",
"dp/1515556524991.jpg"
];`

Comment: I dont see that error with this code.Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I added the html in the question section. I got the result of `{"admin":["640954.jpg"],"dp":["151292.jpg","151269.jpg","1515991.jpg"]}` and test1 and `additional` objects are missing in it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd prefer to have subdirs in arrays too

```js
const path = '/home/user/dir/file';
var next;

path.split('/').reverse().forEach(name => {
  if (name === "") return;
  if (typeof(next) === 'undefined') {
    next = [String(name)];
  } else {
    var current = {};
    current[name] = next;
    next = [current];
  }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(next));
// [{"home":[{"user":[{"dir":["file"]}]}]}]
```

Then objects can be joined