# Convert Array of Paths into Object Array groupings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I did find this question [How to convert an array of paths into JSON structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248245/how-to-convert-an-array-of-paths-into-json-structure) but, I can't seem to manipulate the answer to achieve what I want.

I have an array of Paths that I want to turn into an object that can be easily used on the client.

```
[
    "\\Folder\file.xlsx",
    "\\Folder\file2.xlsx",
    "\\Folder\file3.docx",
    "\\Folder\Folder2\file4.xlsx",
    "\\Folder\Folder2\Folder3\file5.xlsx",
    "\\Folder\Folder2\file6.xlsx",
    "\\Folder\Folder4\file7.pdf"
    "\\Folder\Folder4\Folder5\1. file8.pdf"
]
```

I'm trying to get an output that looks something like this:

```
output = {
    Folder: {
        {
            file: file.xlsx,
            path: \\Folder\file.xlsx

        }, 
        {
            file: file2.xlsx,
            path: \\Folder\file2.xlsx
        }, 
        {
            file: file3.xlsx,
            path: \\Folder\file3.docx
        }
        Folder2: {

                {
                    file: file4.xlsx,
                    path: \\Folder\Folder2\file4.xlsx
                }, 
                Folder3:{

                        {
                            file: file5.xlsx,
                            path: \\Folder\Folder2\Folder3\file5.xlsx
                        },

                },
                {
                    file: file6.docx,
                    path: \\Folder\Folder2\file6.xlsx
                } 
        },
        Folder4: {
            {
                file: file7.pdf,
                path: \\Folder\Folder4\file7.pdf
            },
            Folder5: {
                {
                    file: 1. file8.pdf,
                    path: \\Folder\Folder4\Folder5\1. file8.pdf
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

currently, I have this which gives me empty objects but no path:

```
        var output = {};
        var current;

        for (var a = 0; a < files.length; a++) {
            var s = files[a].split("\\");
            // console.log("s ===> ", s);
            current = output;

            for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                if (s[i] != "") {
                    if (current[s[i]] == null) {
                        current[s[i]] = {};
                    } else {
                        current = current[s[i]];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But it doesn't return quite what I am looking for. I'm not entirely sure if there are functions like map or reduce that can help with this as I'm quite new to Javascript.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: @YongQuan can you tell me what is wrong with it? Maybe I wrote it incorrectly. I need to be able to then display a file system on the client side of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work recursively so you can go deeper like `\\Folder\\........\\Folder10\\file.doc`;

```js
const files = [
  "\\Folder\\file.xlsx",
  "\\Folder\\file2.xlsx",
  "\\Folder\\file3.docx",
  "\\Folder\\Folder2\\file4.xlsx",
  "\\Folder\\Folder2\\Folder3\\file5.xlsx",
  "\\Folder\\Folder2\\file6.xlsx",
  "\\Folder\\Folder4\\file7.pdf",
  "\\Folder\\Folder4\\Folder5\\1. file8.pdf"
];

const result = files.reduce((obj, p) => {

  let temp = obj;
  p.split('\\').forEach((d, i, arr) => {
    if (!d) return;
    if (i === 0) return;
    if (i === arr.length - 1) {
      temp['files'] = [...(temp['files'] || []), {
        file: d,
        path: p
      }];
    } else if (!temp[d]) {
      temp[d] = {};
    }
    temp = temp[d];
  });

  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Direct files of a folder are in `files` array.

```
{
  "Folder": {
    "files": [
      {
        "file": "file.xlsx",
        "path": "\\Folder\\file.xlsx"
      },
      {
        "file": "file2.xlsx",
        "path": "\\Folder\\file2.xlsx"
      },
      {
        "file": "file3.docx",
        "path": "\\Folder\\file3.docx"
      }
    ],
    "Folder2": {
      "files": [
        {
          "file": "file4.xlsx",
          "path": "\\Folder\\Folder2\\file4.xlsx"
        },
        {
          "file": "file6.xlsx",
          "path": "\\Folder\\Folder2\\file6.xlsx"
        }
      ],
      "Folder3": {
        "files": [
          {
            "file": "file5.xlsx",
            "path": "\\Folder\\Folder2\\Folder3\\file5.xlsx"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "Folder4": {
      "files": [
        {
          "file": "file7.pdf",
          "path": "\\Folder\\Folder4\\file7.pdf"
        }
      ],
      "Folder5": {
        "files": [
          {
            "file": "1. file8.pdf",
            "path": "\\Folder\\Folder4\\Folder5\\1. file8.pdf"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this works almost perfectly but for some reason, my output has an empty object key.  https://pasteboard.co/HvUjO4a.jpg  is this the function that creates this?

Comment: I don't know what your input looks like

Comment: Ah it's not your function - I'm using `node-dir` and the path names are looking like `\\\\Folder\\file.xlsx` so the extra `\\` is causing the issue - just not sure the best way to remove the extra `\\`

Comment: I added `if (!d) return;` in the code to check if `d` exists and it works great now! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example with `map` and `reduce` :)

Watch out, your expected output is not valid, so i've adjusted a bit to what seems the most natural.

```js
const files = [
    "\\Folder\\file.xlsx",
    "\\Folder\\file2.xlsx",
    "\\Folder\\file3.docx",
    "\\Folder\\Folder2.xlsx",
    "\\Folder\\Folder2\\file4.xlsx",
    "\\Folder\\Folder3\\file5.xlsx",
    "\\Folder\\Folder3\\file6.docx",
    "\\Folder\\Folder4\\file7.pdf"
];

const result = files.map(filePath => 
({
  path: filePath, 
  file: filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('\\')+1)
})).reduce((acc, item) => {
  const folderPath = item.path.substring(0, item.path.length-(item.file.length+1));
  const folder = folderPath.substring(folderPath.lastIndexOf('\\')+1);
  acc[folder] = acc[folder] || [];
  acc[folder].push(item);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Here is a small explanation:

First, you `map` your files to the expected objects, then, you re-organize them with `reduce`! You pipe both `map` and `reduce` and it is doing the job!

Comment: I incorrectly asked the question and I have updated the question. I didn't embed the folder structure for the output and also some files seem to have numbers like `1. file8.pdf` too.

Comment: Your output is still invalid, but I see your idea. Gonna rewrite it!

Comment: Actually, I'll be glad to edit, but once you will have fixed your expected output. Look at it, let's take the `Folder2`, it has a nested folder `Folder3`, which is ok, but the two files has no key.