# how to structure a filesystem-like JSON from an array of objects with an absolute path

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a JSON file for a fileSystem. I've found something interesting in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248245/how-to-convert-an-array-of-paths-into-json-structure) but I need to get a result like this:

```
{path: 'root',
  size: 24,
  isEmpty: false,
  isDir: true,
  lastModified: 156727373,
  children: [
        {path: 'root/folder1',
         size: 24,
         isEmpty: false,
         isDir: true,
         lastModified: 156727373,
         children: [{
               size:10,
               name:'file1',
               isDir:true,
               isEmpty:true,
               lastModified:10123123123
        }, {
               size:10,
               name:"file2",
               isDir:true,
               isEmpty:true,
               lastModified:10123123123
        }, {
               size:10,
               name:'file3',
               isDir:true,
               isEmpty:true,
               lastModified:10123123123}]}
```

From an array of data with a key "path" with a value of the absolute path. Like this:

```
data:[{
    "path":"/root/folder1",
    "children":[
         {
            "size":10,
            "name":"file1",
            "isDir":true,
            "isEmpty":true,
            "lastModified":10123123123
         },
         {
            "size":10,
            "name":"file2",
            "isDir":true,
            "isEmpty":false,
            "lastModified":10123123123
         },
         {
            "size":10,
            "name":"file3",
            "isDir":false,
            "isEmpty":true,
            "lastModified":10123123123
         }
      ]}, {
    "path":"/root",
    "children":[
         {
            "size":10,
            "name":"folder1",
            "isDir":true,
            "isEmpty":false,
            "lastModified":10123123123
         }
      ]}
]
```

In details:
I have a database table where every row represents a directory with: absolute path and children with their informations. clicking on a children directory will trigger an async request, asking for the data of the children of that directory and the DB will create a row of that directory data. the absolute path will be used to sort the various folders in a JSON with the whole filesystem tree.

I have tried:

```
var output = {};
var current;

for(var a=0; a<data.length; a++) {
  var s = data[a].path.split('/');
  current = output;
  for(var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
    if(s[i] != '') {
      if(current[s[i]] == null) current[s[i]] = {};
      current = current[s[i]];
    }
  }
}
```

but I don't need to set an empty object if it doesn't exist and the only result I can get is a circular structure so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: please add some data and the expected result.

Comment: Did you mean to write `var s = data[a].path.split('/)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the given path and the name of each children and find this object. Then update the object.

```js
var data = [{ path: "/root/folder1", children: [{ size: 10, name: "file1", isDir: true, isEmpty: true, lastModified: 10123123123 }, { size: 10, name: "file2", isDir: true, isEmpty: false, lastModified: 10123123123 }, { size: 10, name: "file3", isDir: false, isEmpty: true, lastModified: 10123123123 }] }, { path: "/root", children: [{ size: 10, name: "folder1", isDir: true, isEmpty: false, lastModified: 10123123123 }] }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { path, children }) => {
        var temp = path.slice(1).split('/');
        children.forEach((o) => {
            Object.assign(
                temp
                    .concat(o.name)
                    .map((_, i, a) => a.slice(0, i + 1).join('/'))
                    .reduce((q, path, i) => {
                        var temp = (q.children = q.children || []).find(p => p.path === path);
                        if (!temp) q.children.push(temp = { path });
                        return temp;
                    }, r),
                o
            );
        });
        return r;
    }, {}).children[0];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```