# How to convert an array of paths into tree object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to convert an array of file&folder paths into tree object(an array of object below, the children points to the array of itself):

```
type TreeItem<T> = {
  title: T
  key: T
  type: 'tree' | 'blob'
  children: Array<TreeItem<T>>
}
```

The file&folder paths come from the "git ls-tree -r -t HEAD" command which lists the tree object of a git repository, it looks as below:

```
100644 blob 68afe6febb3f4ab2155b436e2e5a43f62399388b    LICENSE
100644 blob 78d926deaf73e93c12257d0be9dc10f39662aad0    README.md
040000 tree eefd18d086bb6089a4e392bda3105fd32399146b    app
100644 blob 631e6d753849db0ed05d0124ab62c8e5522f1c32    app/.npmrc
100644 blob 72da957f1fec5b3dec8e89e9ab9364bb96a929b0    app/.yarnrc
100644 blob cb66e81274ca308805350d8c1ccc68811994ed1c    app/app-info.ts
100644 blob 1bf399b381dab7c260c1dc4126025c7ab1a437af    app/git-info.ts
100644 blob ec6e40fb46f6554d62823e5f27a8743de594acff    app/package-info.ts
100644 blob bf92f9a597bfd8b8e9b2308a4848faa6937f4a1e    app/package.json
040000 tree dd30a6b5ee422a42da4561ea8443ef8a4a82c078    app/src
040000 tree c8473c433cf8ec2a3d9b67171cff665d7176f264    app/src/ask-pass
100644 blob 76adbc48d6d239fd39eab1ea08c8ee2408df3ece    app/src/ask-pass/ask-pass.ts
100644 blob e1de6d753ce44680071ab7c67615e2d81b279c21    app/src/ask-pass/main.ts
...
```

As you see, I can tell wheter it's a file or folder by the second column. And I defined a structure as below for the file&folder object above:

```
interface GitTreeObject {
  readonly type: string
  readonly hash: string
  readonly path: string
}
```

Which means I want to convert the Array<'GitTreeObject> into Array<'TreeItem>.
Anyone know how to implement the convert? It's better to implement by Typescript.Thanks in advance.

My requiment is similar with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248245/how-to-convert-an-array-of-paths-into-json-structure), and I tried to reference the answer of that question, but failed

Comment: Please show your attempt(s).

Comment: in which form do you have the data, what is the wanted format of the result?

Comment: cant you make recursive function according the "\" to represent folder until its name without "\" ?

Answer (score 14):

By taking only the pathes, you could split them an reduce the path until you get an object. In this object, you could later add the wanted data.

```js
var data = ['LICENSE', 'README.md', 'app', 'app/.npmrc', 'app/.yarnrc', 'app/app-info.ts', 'app/git-info.ts', 'app/package-info.ts', 'app/package.json', 'app/src', 'app/src/ask-pass', 'app/src/ask-pass/ask-pass.ts', 'app/src/ask-pass/main.ts'],
    result = {};
    
data.forEach(p => p.split('/').reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, result));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I did an infinite amount of math to do this and you came up with a oneliner.

Comment: Does `o` and `k` have meaning or are you just trolling?

Comment: @EricMajerus, it could be read as *object* and *key*. but it wouldn't fit into window.

Comment: Just coincidence that it ends up saying "ok" then :laughing: