# NodeJS convert array of paths into JSON

Tags: arrays, node.js, object

is there an easy way of converting a list of objects with path=>value pairs (e.g.)

```
path: /wip/bish/name // value: bing
path: /wip/bash/name // value: bang
path: /wip/bosh/name // value: bong
```

so that i end up with a json object like:

```
{
   "wip": {
       "bish": {
           "name": "bing"
       },
       "bash": {
           "name": "bang"
       },
       "bosh: {
           "name": "bong"
       }
   }
}
```

source data looks like:

```
{ Parameters:
    [ 
        { 
            Name: '/wip/bish/name',            
            Value: 'bing' 
        },
        { 
            Name: '/wip/bash/name',
            Value: 'bang'
        },
        { 
            Name: '/wip/bosh/name',            
            Value: 'bong'
        }
    ] 
}
```

Comment: Maybe this post will help [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248245/how-to-convert-an-array-of-paths-into-json-structure)

Comment: what does your raw data look like? is it in a text file? how are you getting it?

Comment: @MattOestreich - updated question with source data.

Comment: @Turtl3 - that example only handles paths, i need paths and values :)

Answer (score 0):

turns out theres a package called 'flat' with a function 'unflatten' that solves my problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat

```
var unflatten = require('flat').unflatten

unflatten({
    'three.levels.deep': 42,
    'three.levels': {
        nested: true
    }
})

// {
//     three: {
//         levels: {
//             deep: 42,
//             nested: true
//         }
//     }
// }
```