# Convert File Paths into JSON Tree Structure

Tags: json, algorithm, dictionary, go, maps

I want to convert File Paths into a JSON Tree like structure.
For more information -
[Convert Array of filepaths into JSON Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248245/how-to-convert-an-array-of-paths-into-json-structure)
[Convert file path into tree view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844499/how-to-convert-a-file-path-into-treeview)

Here is my input data -

```
/home/aneesh/Code/GmailProject/main.py, 55
/home/aneesh/Code/Parser/parse.py, 66
/home/user/Project/image.png, 77
/home/user/Music/output.wav, 88
...
```

Here is the desired output -

```json
{
    "home": {
        "aneesh": {
            "Code": {
                "GmailProject": {
                    "main.py": 55
                },
                "Parser": {
                    "parse.py": 66
                }
            }
        },
        "user": {
            "Project": {
                "image.png": 77
            },
            "Music": {
                "output.wav": 88
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having issues re-implementing this even though the logic is extremely simple due to Go's type system. Unlike in python I cant just have a map of map of maps... variably. And using a map[string]int won't do. Any ideas?

I tried to implement a recursive algorithm but that does not work as I cannot recurse into the maps I have. I'm also passing my maps by reference so my function can make changes in memory.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    l := /home/aneesh/Code/Python/main.py
    m := make(map[string]bool, 10)
}

func arrange(m *map[string]any, s string) {
    arr := strings.Split(s, "/")[1:]

    ma := *m
    for i, e := range arr {
        if i == len(arr)-1 {
            ma[e] = true
        } else {
            ma = ma[e]
        }
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/rWqwrLkEhQy

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What specific problems did you encounter?

Comment: ```
func arrange(m *map[string]any, s string) {
 arr := strings.Split(s, "/")[1:]

 ma := *m
 for i, e := range arr {
  if i == len(arr)-1 {
   ma[e] = true
  } else {
   ma = ma[e]
  }
 }
}

```

Coming from python I used an approach that would eventually be recursive, but I faced a problem here in reassigning ma = ma[e]. (In this case im using a bool as the last element instead of an int.
But I get an Incompatible assign error

Comment: @mkopriva https://go.dev/play/p/rWqwrLkEhQy Put it on go playground

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```golang
func parse(s string) (path []string, line int) {
    if len(s) > 0 && s[0] == '/' {
        s = s[1:]
    }

    if i := strings.LastIndexByte(s, ','); i > -1 {
        num, err := strconv.Atoi(strings.TrimSpace(s[i+1:]))
        if err != nil {
            /* don't */ panic(err)
        }
        line = num
        s = s[:i]
    }

    path = strings.Split(s, "/")
    return path, line
}
```

```golang
func makeobj(input []string) map[string]any {
    obj := make(map[string]any)
    cur := obj
    for _, entry := range input {
        path, line := parse(entry)
        for i, last := 0, len(path)-1; i < len(path); i++ {
            key := path[i]
            if i == last {
                cur[key] = line
                break
            }

            v, ok := cur[key].(map[string]any)
            if !ok || v == nil {
                v = make(map[string]any)
                cur[key] = v
            }
            cur = v
        }
        cur = obj
    }
    return obj
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/7IiQApI2e59

Comment: Could you share an example of how I would use this to make a map with the 2 following paths -
  
"/home/aneesh/Code/multi-file-scanner-rewrite/tests/data/magic_test_data/test_password_doc"  
"/home/user/Code/multi-file-scanner-rewrite/libm/bin/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"

Comment: There's a playground link in the answer, update the input and run it.

Comment: oh, sorry! didnt see it. Thank you so much!